# Reference to static member function & inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, callback, libuv

I'm using libuv in a C++ program. I have two classes, A and B that inherit from C.

I use libuv and declared an instance of `uv_signal_t` on C. Creating an instance of `uv_signal_t` requires a callback to be passed. I can easily pass a lambda to the C function to go around the problem of references to static member functions:

```
const int32_t r = uv_signal_start(&this->signal, [](uv_signal_t *handle, int signum){}, SIGABRT);
```

But how can I provide a different implementation of the callback on each child class? Ideally I'd have some common code implemented on C.cpp and additional code on each child.

**Update**

To be clear, I cannot change the signature of the callback method, as it's defined by libuv. I could edit the source for libuv, but I'm not sure I want to go that deep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll add a function pointer as a property to my class C and implement it as necessary on the derived classes. More [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/2tpvkm/reference_to_static_member_function_inheritance/).

Answer (score -1):

I think you can capture `this` pointer in the lambda, and call a virtual function through this. The virtual function can be overrided in derived classes then.

```
 const int32_t r = uv_signal_start(&this->signal, [this](uv_signal_t *handle, int signum){ return this->callback(); }, SIGABRT);
```

Comment: error: 'this' cannot be implicitly captured in this context

Comment: then capture explicitly.

Comment: I can't change the signature of the lambda.

Comment: I don't think capture is part of signature of the closure.

Comment: Btw, uv_xxx_t has a data field, you can set it to this, that's the usual way to pass data.

Comment: Won't I be overwriting any data sets data to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69623/discussion-between-lapinrigolo-and-min-lin).

Comment: As libuv was a wrapper to libev on Linux, there is no data field in libev, you need to make your own by inheriting the handle. Data is introduced in libuv for your convenience to put custom data. That's what it meant for.